# Best App Server container for AWS Cloud

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services

I am planning to develop a web app that gets deployed in AWS cloud and auto scales.

Web app is pretty much standard in terms of functionality. 
1) Static HTML/UI will be part of Web Server and make calls to Application server via Web SErvices.
2) Application server will be bunch of Web services.
3) AWS will auto scale the deployment based on configuration we set. It will replicate image of app server and web server.

Question is:
1) What is the best container to use for App Server? I prefer tomcat along with spring MVC framework. But I am not sure if thats the best for AWS? Does any one have any experience in selecting right container for App Server?

Goal is to program in J2EE.

Comment: These days it sucks to ask question on SO. Don't understand the question or not related to what I know, lets vote negatively. Atleast you can add comment why you vote negatively?  And Why judge some one. If you don't know the answer or the problem is beyond your scope of understanding, that does not mean the question is wrong.

Comment: look at the reasons people are flagging your question to be closed. Your question is "off topic" and "primarily opinion based". That should be all you need to know. By the way, if you prefer Tomcat then use Tomcat, that's what most people use for Java on AWS.

Comment: Thx mbaird - thats what I was looking for what most people use? - And atleast I know why it was put on hold? Thanks for putting up details. Although I don't agree with the ideology. Not every problem is well defined that can be answered binary. And opinions do matter. They give you perspective..

Comment: you might not agree, but the the people that run this site don't want those type of questions here, so there's no point in arguing.

Comment: yup need a better place than SO. this one is getting judgemental and restrictive.

Comment: No, it's just not a general discussion forum like you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using AWS's Elastic Beanstalk to auto-scale then Tomcat is you only J2EE option as far as I am aware